# What was the original German word Cantor used for "countable" and/or "uncountable"

Tags: elementary-set-theory, reference-request, cardinals, math-history

Apologies if this is slightly off-topic - it's about history of mathematics, but linguistic history specifically:  I suspect I'd get a better answer here than the language SE site due to domain knowledge.

I was explaining the concept of countably vs. uncountably infinite sets to a friend, and he had a (probably-not-uncommon?) viscerally negative reaction to that terminology.

So I started wondering: ***how closely do those English terms - "countable" and "uncountable" - hew to whatever the original German terms Cantor published?***  I.e., is this a problem of translation or just a normal specialized-jargon-can-be-confusing issue?

Comment: Todays German terminology 'abzählbar' seems to me very close to 'countable'. I don't know what Cantor used. But tagging your question with 'math-history' might be appropriate.

Comment: Also try http://hsm.stackexchange.com

Comment: Cantor's seminal 1874 paper, demonstrating more than one "infinity" exists, is [Über eine Eigenschaft des Inbegriffes aller reellen algebraischen Zahlen](http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/pdfcache/PPN243919689_0077/PPN243919689_0077___LOG_0014.pdf).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In his 1874 paper [*Ueber eine Eigenschaft des Inbegriffes aller reellen algebraischen Zahlen*](http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/pdfcache/PPN243919689_0077/PPN243919689_0077___LOG_0014.pdf) [PDF] he shows that the algebraic numbers are countable, while the continuum is not, but he does not introduce terms for countability or uncountability. In the 1879 paper [*Ueber unendliche, lineare Punktmannichfaltigkeiten*](http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/img/?PPN=PPN235181684_0015&DMDID=DMDLOG_0004) he uses *abzählbar* ‘countable’. He gives examples of countable sets of reals and examples of uncountable sets of reals, including

> Jede Punktmenge, welche aus einem stetigen Intervalle dadurch hervorgeht, dass man eine *endliche* oder *abzählbar unendliche* Mannigfaltigkeit von Punkten $\omega_1,\omega_2,\ldots,\omega_\nu,\ldots$ daraus entfernt.

I.e., every point set that results by removing a *finite* or *countably infinite* collection of points $\omega_1,\omega_2,\ldots,\omega_\nu,\ldots$.

As was noted in the comments, *abzählbar* corresponds rather precisely to *countable* in a literal sense.